# How to convert an array of objects back to one object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I got an array of objects that has the following structure:

```
const cars = {
  ford: {
    entries: ['ford 150']
  },
  chrysler: {
    entries: ['Voyager']
  },
  honda: {
    entries: []
  },
  toyota: {
    entries: ['sienna']
  },
  mercedes: {
    entries: []
  },
}
```

For the user to be able to rearrange the order of the cars, I need to filter out the car brands that have zero entries, so I do this:

```
const filteredCars = Object.values(cars).filter(removeCarsWithNoEntries)

function removeCarsWithNoEntries(e) {
  if (e.entries[0]) return e.entries
}
```

Then, once the order is rearranged, I have to convert the object back to its original form, but with the order rearranged, meaning something like this:

```
cars = {
   toyota: {
    entries: ['sienna']
  },
  chrysler: {
    entries: ['Voyager']
  },
  ford: {
    entries: ['ford 150']
  },
  honda: {
    entries: []
  },
  mercedes: {
    entries: []
  },
}
```

I've read upon `array.reduce` and `Object.assign` but so far the things I have tried do not work.

How can I convert the array of objects back to one single object **with** the original car brands that had 0 entries? Thanks.

Comment: Objects aren't semantically ordered data structures; use an array if order matters, then you can sort it.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the object to entries via `Object.entries()`, and then filter/sort by the value (the 2nd item in the pair), and convert back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const cars = {"ford":{"entries":["ford 150"]},"chrysler":{"entries":["Voyager"]},"honda":{"entries":[]},"toyota":{"entries":["sienna"]},"mercedes":{"entries":[]}}

const sorted = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(cars)
    .sort(([, { entries: a }], [, { entries: b }]) => b.length - a.length)
)

const filtered = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(cars)
    .filter(([, v]) => v.entries.length)
)

console.log({ sorted, filtered })
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking your code... the `filter` method doesn't works because return an array...
do you need use `length` property to check if has values, otherwise it will always be `true`

```js
const cars = {
  ford: {
    entries: ['ford 150']
  },
  chrysler: {
    entries: ['Voyager']
  },
  honda: {
    entries: []
  },
  toyota: {
    entries: ['sienna']
  },
  mercedes: {
    entries: []
  },
}

filtered = {}

Object.keys(cars).forEach(removeCarsWithNoEntries)

function removeCarsWithNoEntries(brand) {
  if(!cars[brand].entries.length) return
  filtered[brand] = cars[brand]
}

console.log(filtered)
```